# website layout changing on browser window resizing

Tags: html, css, layout, web

For a website I'm making, I'm using percentages for the divs and so when I resize the browser window, the website layout gets messed up. How should I keep using percentages and make the layout stay the way it is upon browser resizing?

Comment: This can have lots of reasons, depending on your actual layout and contents. Without seeing some actual code it will be difficult to provide a useful answer.

Comment: Breaking how? When it gets too wide, or too narrow?

Comment: meaning if i reduce the window size, the divs become narrower and narrower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you set width in %, try setting min-width and max-width in px

[Check this](http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=199)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `min-width` attribute to prevent your layout from shrinking beyond a certain size.

```
div { min-width: 500px; }
```

[Browser support](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width#compatibilitysection) IE7 behaves incorrectly when min-width is specified for input elements. Although I doubt that comes into play for your site layout.

Comment: does min-width only support pixels?

Comment: Min-width supports px, em and % just like any other width spec.